# How many Google accounts can one mobile number confirm?

Tags: google-account

Google says there is a limit but doesn't specify a number.

> - There are too many accounts with the same phone number. If you see the error message, "This phone number has already created the maximum
>     number of accounts," you'll have to use a different number. To help
>     prevent abuse, **we limit the number of accounts that can be associated
>     with each phone number**.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171664

Comment: I suspect the number is probably not published in order to prevent people from signing up for the maximum minus one.

Comment: Why? What happens to a person who's reached the limit?

Comment: Beats me. I'm sure it's just an anti-spam measure.